# Basis for $V$ over $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $\mathbb{C}$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$. Let
\begin{align*}
V=\{(z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4) \in \mathbb{C^{4}} | \bar{z_1} =z_1, \bar{z_2} =z_4 , \bar{z_3}= -z_3 \} \end{align*}

How can i find a basis for $V$ over $\mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I've shown that $V$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{C^4}$ over $\mathbb{R}$. I tried to find the basis but can't think of it, just need a hint.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The first and third condition suggests $z_1$ is real and $z_3$ is purely imaginary. The second condition simply suggests that if $z_2 = a+bi$ then$ z_4 = a - bi$. So every vector in $V$ of the form: $(a, b+ci, di, b-ci)$ where $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{R}$. Can you take it from here?